# How to make create action work with AJAX and jQuery in Rails 4, when using nested attributes?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to learn how to use AJAX and jQuery in Rails 4. I'm using nested attributes and currently trying to do the create action via AJAX.

Here is my projects index.html.erb view:

```
 <% @projects.each do |project| %>

    ...

    <%= render "idea" %>

    <%= form_for([project, project.ideas.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
       <p><%= f.text_area :description %></p>
       <p><%= button_tag '', :class => 'glyphicon  glyphicon-ok' %></p>
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

_idea.html.erb partial:

```
 <ul class="post">
   <% project.ideas.each do |idea| %>
       <li><%= idea.description %></li>  
   <% end %>
 </ul>
```

ideas_controller.rb

```
def create
    @idea = @project.ideas.new(idea_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @idea.save
            format.html {redirect_to root_path}
            format.js
        else
            render.html {render :new}
            render.js
        end
    end
end
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :projects do
   resources :ideas 
 end
```

Here is my Create.js.erb.

```
$('.post').append("<%= j render("idea") %>")
$(":input:not(input[type=submit])").val("");
```

With this setup I get a NameError in Projects#index, "undefined local variable or method 'project'". 
However, if I change the partial to <%= @project.ideas.each ... I get a "undefined method 'ideas'" error in Projects#index.

My projects_controller.rb index is:

```
 def index
    @projects = Project.all
 end
```

I'm confused on how can I render the 'idea' partial correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you get is because you haven't defined `@project` at all, and `project` is only defined inside the `@projects.each` block in your index view. You can pass the `project` variable to the idea partial as a local variable like this:

```
<%= render partial: "idea", locals:  {project: project} %>
```

But even better, you can render the ideas as collection,  like this:

In the index view:

```
 <ul class="post">
 <%= render partial: "idea", collection:  project.ideas %>
 </ul>
```

Now we do have the 'project' variable as we're inside the @projects.each block.

And in the idea partial:

```
<li><%= idea.description %></li>
```